# How to append elements from second list to existent elements from first list in R

Tags: r, purrr

I have two lists x and y:

```
x <- list(id1 = list(a = list(t = 5)), id2 = list(a = list(t = 1), b = list(t = 3)), id3 = list(a = list(t = 1), b = list(t = 2)))

y <- list(b = list(k = 7))
```

I need to modify x list and add corresponding "b" elements from y list to obtain z list:

```
z <- list(id1 = list(a = list(t = 5)), id2 = list(a = list(t = 1), b = list(t = 3, k = 7)),
  id3 = list(a = list(t = 1), b = list(t = 2, k = 7)))
```

I try to use `list_modify(x, y)` and `list_merge(x, !!!y)` from `purrr` package but obtain wrong result.
How to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you could do:

```r
result <- lapply(x, function(i) {
  if("b" %in% names(i)) i$b <- append(i$b, y$b); i;
  })
```

Such that

```
identical(result, z)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not particularly elegant, but you could use a loop to do this.  The loop goes over the elements in `x` and within that, the elements in `y`.  If there is an element in `x` with the same name as an element in `y`, the two are concatenated together in `z`, otherwise, `z` is just `x`.  Depending on the scale of the real problem, this may be too slow, and perhaps someone can provide a tidy alternative.

```
z <- vector(mode="list", length = length(x))  
for(i in 1:length(x)){
  for(j in 1:length(y)){
    z[[i]] <- x[[i]]
    if(names(y)[j] %in% names(x[[i]])){
      z[[i]][[names(y)[j]]] <- c(x[[i]][[names(y)[j]]], y[[j]])
    }else{
      
    }
    names(z) <- names(x)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `map_if`: apply `list_merge` to every element in the original list that has at least one subname in common with `y`:

```
map_if(x, ~any(names(.) %in% names(y)), list_merge, !!!y)
```

Answer (score 0):

purrr::list_merge works as expected, but when the lists are named it uses the names to find the positions for merging, and your y isn't named properly with id2/id3 for it to merge.

To use list_merge:
`y <- list(id2 = list(b = list(k = 7)), id3 = list(b = list(k = 7)))`

`z2 <- list_merge(x, !!!y)`

`identical(z, z2)`

[1] TRUE